# Mermaid boxes too small in HTML Quarto

Tags: diagram, quarto, mermaid

I am creating a `mermaid` diagram in HTML format in `Quarto`, but the problem is that the boxes are too small for the words in the diagram. Here is a reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Mermaid boxes too small in HTML Quarto"
format: html
---

```{mermaid}
flowchart LR
  A[Data preparation] --> B(Data exploration)
  B --> C{Modelling}
  C --> D[Prediction]
  D --> E[Conclusion]
```
````

Output:

[image]

As you can see, the boxes are too small for the words. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to prevent this (maybe automatically)?

Comment: That is interesting, for me it works like a charm. When I narrow the window, a horizontal scrollbar automatically appears (R version 4.1.2).

Comment: I have the same problem -- boxes are too small in the same way.

Comment: I have same problem, I am trying to set the diagram (per the bottom part of the link below) width but having problems (https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/flowchart.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `\n` to add line breaks or check whether sizing fixes this: https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/diagrams.html#sizing. Also note that the preview differs heavily from the browser view of the HTML.